# Add field in table with layername as value

Tags: expression

I need to merge multiple tables (I'm planning to use "merge" for this). I also need a new column in the original tables that show the name of the source table. Is there a way I can add a field that equals the name of the table? What is the expression I should use in “Field calculator”? I have used hours to find out, but no luck so far =( I’m sadly not familiar with Python.

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: How many tables have you got? If there's less than a dozen it might have been quicker to do it manually than searching for something to do this the 'easy' way. I have done this (in arcpy) so I understand the necessity; I had over 200 tables so it made sense to script it. I'm happy to share that script but if you don't understand python it wont mean much to you and I'm fairly sure that software like ArcMap and QGIS has no $TABLENAME variable you can call on in these situations. Sorry I can't help more specifically but I would need to know the platform to help.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. I'm using ArcGIS 10.2. I have over 100 tables, and I will do the same operation several times in the next few months. It might be easier for me to merge the files in another program (R, Stata etc.), but it would be great do know how to do it in ArcGIS as well. Well, it would be great to see your script, and then I might just have to start learning Python =)